# ConsumerConfig.ALLOW_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_CONFIG = false is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

SpringBoot2
SpringKafka

I'm currently facing an issue where the ConsumerConfig.ALLOW_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_CONFIG = false is not working properly. I've set the allow.auto.create.topics to false, but the Topic still auto created during the runtime.

Here is the code changes that I've made.

EmbeddedKafkaIntegrationTest.java (Unit Test class)

```
package com.mbag.kafka;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafka;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

@SpringBootTest(classes = {KafkaConsumerService.class, KafkaProducerService.class})
@Import(com.mbag.kafka.EmbeddedKafkaIntegrationTest.KafkaConfigurationTest.class)
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = {
        "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092",
        "port=9092",
        "auto.create.topics.enable=true"
})
public class EmbeddedKafkaIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaConsumerService consumer;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaProducerService producer;

    @Value("${test.topic}")
    private String topic;

    @Test
    public void givenEmbeddedKafkaBroker_whenSendingWithSimpleProducer_thenMessageReceived() throws Exception {
        String data = "Sending with our own simple KafkaProducer";

        producer.send(topic, data);

        boolean messageConsumed = consumer.getLatch().await(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        assertTrue(messageConsumed);
        assertTrue(consumer.getPayload().contains(data));
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableKafka
    static class KafkaConfigurationTest {

        @Bean
        public KafkaAdmin admin() {
            Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
            configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
            return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
        }

        @Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
            factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
            factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(record -> record.value().contains("test"));
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        public ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory() {
            return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
        }

        @Bean
        public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.ALLOW_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_CONFIG, "false");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest"); // earliest latest
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "localtest");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
            return props;
        }

        @Bean
        public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
            Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
            configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
            configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
            configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
            return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
        }

        @Bean
        public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
            return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
        }

    }

}
```

KafkaConsumerService.java

```
package com.mbag.kafka;

import lombok.Data;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.RetryableTopic;
import org.springframework.kafka.retrytopic.FixedDelayStrategy;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Backoff;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

@Component
@Data
public class KafkaConsumerService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumer.class);

    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private String payload;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${test.topic}", groupId = "localtest", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord) {
        LOGGER.info("Received payload='{}'", consumerRecord.toString());
        payload = consumerRecord.toString();
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public void resetLatch() {
        latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    }

}
```

KafkaProducerService.java

```
package com.mbag.kafka;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class KafkaProducerService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaProducer.class);

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public void send(String topic, String payload) {
        LOGGER.info("sending payload='{}' to topic='{}'", payload, topic);
        kafkaTemplate.send(topic, payload);
    }

}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      group-id: localtest
      properties:
        allow.auto.create.topics: false
test:
  topic: embedded-test-topic
  topic-test: testing-only
```

Based on above code changes, I did some testing by changing the flag between broker and consumer.

1. If I changed the auto.create.topics.enable=false on broker level, the test case will failed due to unable to subscribe the topic. This is fine since expected the behavior.
2. If I enable the auto.create.topics.enable=true, but I disabled the allow.auto.create.topics=false, the topic still auto created. This is not fine as unexpected behavior.

I've checked the logs in console and debug mode, the property is indeed set to false. But things just don't work as expected.

Above testing is using @EmbeddedKafka. I did tried to use TestContainers Kafka, and the result still the same. Not working.

Can someone please advise if I make any incorrect changes here?

**UPDATE:**
After some testing, it seems like the topic was created during the Producer part.
I created a simple test cases for consume (without produce code), the topic didn't get created.
I created another simple test cases for produce (without consume code), I saw the topic being created automatically.

Does anyone know how do I disable the topic auto creation on producer? Or if this is intended feature?

I'm understand I can disable the topic auto creation on broker level (auto.create.topics.enable=false). However, sometimes we may not allow to modify the properties on infra level.

Comment: In EmbeddedKafka I see auto.create.topics.enable=true

Comment: Hi @Mar-Z, I set it to true to test the allow.auto.create.topics flag on Consumer level. If consumer flag set to false, the topic shouldn't be auto created.

By the way, I realised the issue seems caused by Producer side. When the producer send a request to the broker, the topic will get auto created. I've updated the ticket description with my latest finding.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I disable the topic auto creation on producer?

You would disable auto creation on the broker.

Ideally, you'd also disallow from the consumer. Otherwise, you'd be making empty topics with no active producer (for example, you mistype the topic name, and you'd get no messages or warning since the topic would be created empty).

Use AdminClient on your own to actually create topics before other tests run.